# Is there a way to store pdf files in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, browser

I am trying to store a base-64 encoded pdf file into firestore, but the base-64 text is too long to store to the database is there a way to compress the text before storing?

I tried the main program at first this is what I got:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Document 'projects/jeel-al-ebdaa/databases/(default)/documents/Teachers/testteacher' cannot be written because its size (1,377,477 bytes) exceeds the maximum allowed size of 1,048,576 bytes.
```

I know this means the text is too long.
I can not find a way to compress the text in pure vanilla js

Comment: Did you try a web search for "javascript compress string"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it can be possible using compressing and decompressing data algorithms, So many algorithms for that but I recement use [DEFLATE algorithm](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9577665B2/en) for compressing data.
and in JavaScript [zlib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlib) library is used for compressing data, it's based on DEFLATE algorithm you can install that library using npm or yarn.

```
npm install zlib
```

after that you create  code that compresses`zlib.deflate()` your pdf size ;

here it's  example:-

```
const zlib = require('zlib');

const buffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');

zlib.deflate(buffer, (err, compressedBuffer) => {
 if (err) {
   console. Error(err);
   return;
 }

   const compressedBase64String = compressedBuffer.toString('base64');

    // Store the compressed base-64 string in Firestore
    firestore.collection('myCollection').doc('myDoc').set({
    compressedPdf: compressedBase64String
    });
  });
```

and for decompress for use `zlib.inflate()` example:-

```
const compressedBuffer = Buffer.from(compressedBase64String, 'base64');

// Decompress the buffer using the zlib library
zlib.inflate(compressedBuffer, (err, decompressedBuffer) => {
   if (err) {
    console. Error(err);
    return;
     }
  const decompressedBase64String = decompressedBuffer.toString('base64');

    });
```

Comment: i cant use zlib with svelte also this app runs on the browser

Comment: thanks anyway ill research ways to use zlib